# Python Paramiko Expect Not Catching Prompt

Tags: python, bash, paramiko

I am trying to use paramiko_expect to automate a process that involves multiple password inputs. Here is the script:

```
pass_prompt = '*password for*'


with SSHClientInteraction(client, display=True) as interact:

    interact.send('cd')
    interact.send('dzdo su - ALTUSER')
    interact.expect(pass_prompt)
    interact.send('PASSWORD')

client.close
```

And here is the output:

```
cd
dzdo su - ALTUSER
[user@SERVER ~]$ cd
[user@SERVER ~]$ dzdo su - ALTUSER
[dzdo] password for USER:
```

The script is not catching the expect output, I have tried multiple wildcard positions. The script will run all lines, then it will at the end prompt for password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
pass_prompt = '.*password for.*'
```

Wildcard required .* on my version of bash.

Comment: confirmation in the source documentation: regular expressions are expected: https://github.com/fgimian/paramiko-expect/blob/master/paramiko_expect.py